# SQL Union or Join to calculate averages from several tables

Tags: sql, join, union

Suppose I have several such tables that I need to calculate average the values based on the same timestamp.What is the best way to do it.Should I do outer Join and then calculate average for each row or union and then look for similar timestamp?

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|             Time|TimeStamp        |            value|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       Some date |            41526|14               |
|       Some date |            41536|12               |
|       Some date |            41546|32               |
|       Some date |            41555|10               |
|       Some date |            41567|20               |
|       Some date |            41588|15               |
|                 |            41599|12               |

+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|             Time|TimeStamp        |            value|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       Some date |            41526|14               |
|       Some date |            41536|12               |
|       Some date |            41546|32               |
|       Some date |            41555|10               |
|       Some date |            41547|20               |
|       Some date |            41588|15               |
|                 |            41620|15               |
```

Here is resulting table example(

```
    +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
    |             Time|TimeStamp        |            mean |
    +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
    |       Some date |            41526|23.32            |
    |       Some date |            41536|43.22            |
    |       Some date |            41546|54.32            |
    |
```

Comment: Depends on what you want. Better sample data and also the expected result would make it easier to understand.

Comment: I want to do averages of several tables according to timestamp

Comment: Which averages?

Comment: Of the values in the tables

Comment: Average the value based on the same timestamp? What is your base field that you want to group on? Can you provide an example of your expected result?

Comment: Yes based on the same timestamp.I think timestamp

Comment: Just add `time` column to Gordon's answer. That's the simplest way to get at your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want `union` and `group by`.  Something like this:

```
select time, timestamp, avg(value)
from ((select time, timestamp, value from table1) union all
      (select time, timestamp, value from table2) union all
      (select time, timestamp, value from table3)
     ) t
group by time, timestamp;
```

Comment: Add the `time` column to the `SELECT` and `GROUP`. That should get what Yakov is after.

Comment: @Yakov . . . This seems to do what you want.  I'm not sure expressing this as a `join` would be very easy.